# Can't bind to some objects in WPF using Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, data-binding, expression-blend

I create a new Window and try to set my Class `FooService` as DataContext property. But in the "Select Object" dialog I can only find some of the classes but not the `FooService`.

Any Idea if there are any requirements for classes to be listed in that dialog?

Comment: Did you compile the application after you created that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does FooService have a public parameter-less constructor?  If not, Blend won't see it.

Comment: I guess that could be the problem. Because all other calsses are found even without setting something in xaml. Will verify this later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the appropriate namespace to the list of XML namespaces in the XAML file for the Window.

For example, if your FooService class had a namespace of "Services" you would add an xmlns declaration like so:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:services="clr-namespace:Services"
        ... />
```

or (if it's in a different project that you have referenced)

```
xmlns:services="clr-namespace:Services;assembly=Services"
```

Assuming that project's name is "Services".